# Convert repository Maven to sbt resolver

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I wonder what is the equivalent of this maven repository in sbt:
maven:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>hwr</id>
        <name>Hortonworks repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring</id>
        <name>Spring repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I wonder where can I add the id parameter in sbt:

```
resolvers += "Hortonworks repository" at "https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "Spring repository" at "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration should work. Don't think you need to add the id parameter in sbt.

```scala
resolvers += "Hortonworks repository" at "https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "Spring repository" at "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"
```